# The nature of the electromagnetic induction

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

the electromagnetic induction:  is it a magnetic force (Lorentz Force) or an electric force generated by the temporal variation of the magnetic field (Faraday's law)?

Comment: What does Wikipedia say that you don't follow? That might be the best way to get an answer.

Comment: I've seen "Electromagnetic or Magnetic induction is the production of an electromotive force or voltage across an electrical conductor due to its dynamic interaction with a magnetic field." But the existence of a magnetic field does not imply that there is an electric field?

Answer (score 2):

If your frame of reference is the one of your induction loop then electromagnetic induction of a current is due to the rotational electric field produced by the time change of the magnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

In reality, if you read the very first page of electrodynamics of moving bodies that's what einstein aimed to find and that's what led to relativity. It all depends on frame of reference and are  physically interrelated in the relativity. This one beautiful thought changed the fate of physics.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.